# Checking if user owns item before using

Tags: php

I have a simple market and user customisation system, when a user equips an item it goes to (URL)/render.php?id=**item ID** , in the render.php file it has simple code found below. How would I make the file check if the user actually owns the item before equiping it? (at the moment it doesn't and you can wear stuff you don't own by abusing that)

```
<? include "../../header.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$item = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=" . $_GET['id']);
$gI = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$handler->query("UPDATE `users` SET `$gI->type`='$gI->wearable' WHERE `id`='$myu->id'");
?>
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=/Customize/"></head>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table for `users_items` and use the table to save the users items when a user obtains an item. You would insert a row in this table that links the user to the item, i.e: `id`, `user_id`, `item_id`, then instead of directly selecting from the items table, you select from `users_items` and JOIN from the items table the details of the item.

```
SELECT items.type, 
       items.wearable 
FROM users_items
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = users_items.item_id
WHERE users_items.item_id = ?
```

Then use prepared queries on `?`, instead of string concatenation to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I don't really understand this..?

I already have a table called inventory which has an id, the users id and the item id, how would I select this and read it then go on to execute the rest?

Comment: You Can Get The Items USER have and search in and if he have the item then Update query if not you can Send Error TO USER